# QueryDsl orderBy column name

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I just started to use QueryDSL and ran into a problem. Is it possible to do the orderBy using the column name? I found this for orderBy dynamic path generation:

[Generic querydsl orderBy dynamic path generation with left joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287194/generic-querydsl-orderby-dynamic-path-generation-with-left-joins)

which is great, but in my case the GUI already sends column names for ordering.
For example, "USER_ID" is the column name, and the property is "userid"

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

private String userid;   

@Id     
@Column(name="USER_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, length=18)
public String getUserid() {
    return this.userid;
}
```

}

Extracting property name from column name in hibernate is the only solution I can think of.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PathBuilder` for dynamic path construction

```
PathBuilder<User> pbu = new PathBuilder<>(User.class, "user");
query.orderBy(pbu.getString(orderProperty).asc());
```

Comment: This is fine, but my problem is the presentation side sends column names, not the property name. AFAIK PathBuilder works only with property names?

Comment: If your UI sends column names, your ORM abstraction breaks. You could send them through a naming strategy, but that would be just a workaround.

Comment: I'd like to change the naming strategy as little as possible. Maybe I could pack the querydsl generated classes into my web service client so the gui developer can make the changes in a painless way. I don't know what is the usual practice in this case..

Comment: A good practice would be to use the property names from the client, since you are using an ORM abstraction in between anyway. Providing the querydsl classes to the clients is not necessary, just make them submit the property names instead of column names either via using a naming strategy or being aware of the domain model.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help. I know this is a little of topic. Currently the orderProperty being sent is type string. How can the gui developer be aware of the domain model if I don't pack the generated classes? Hard coding the property names doesn't seem like a clean way to do it.

Comment: The client could have the JPA domain model, no need to bundle any Querydsl generated classes.